# loading an existing project from AEM into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aem

I have an existing AEM project. Is there a way to loading that project into Eclipse or intelliJ. All the articles and forum posts seem to show how to create a new project but nothing for an existing project. I am using AEM 6.4.

Is there a way I can connect to the AEM instance from eclipse to AEM and pull in all the project files directly?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a maven project files then you can import them as a maven project in eclipse and then deploy using the maven build command. But before deploying keep a backup of the content and the component present in the AEM instance.

As we deploy the projects as bundles in AEM, so it will be difficult to pull from AEM to eclipse directly.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, Go to File > Import > Existing Maven Projects. Choose the project location, Eclipse will read the pom.xml files.

[image]